# Formsflow.ai Docker setup: WebAPI and BPM containers don't start properly

Tags: camunda, business-process-management, formsflow.ai, formsflow

I followed the docker installation instructions for Windows with WSL2 and so far have not been able to get the forms-flow-webapi and forms-flow-bpm containers to run. All other containers are running as expected:

[List of formsflow containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KL3Cz.jpg)

In the picture above, you can see forms-flow-webapi and forms-flow-bpm are not running. In fact, they restart constantly and the output can be seen below:

[forms-flow-webapi container output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsjD8.jpg)

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address>
```

[forms-flow-bpm container output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccFrH.jpg)

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/forms-flow-ai/.well-known/openid-configuration": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Both containers restart endlessly, always displaying the same output. I have followed the instructions provided here https://github.com/AOT-Technologies/forms-flow-ai/tree/master/deployment/docker step by step, even tried on different physical machines, always the same.

I have edited the .env files located in `./forms-flow-idm/keycloak/.env`, `./forms-flow-analytics/.env` and `./deployment/docker/.env`. I repeated the installation process several times using the current version available (commit [18a77a](https://github.com/AOT-Technologies/forms-flow-ai/commit/18a77a713f4af70ba077d3821db96970c0c403ae)) and got the same result every single time. I might have missed something but I can't figure out what it is by just looking at the output. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Container keeps restarting.

Comment: You cannot refer to keycloak with localhost:8080 from another container as it looks up within forms-flow-bpm container for 8080 port. So i recommend you to use the system IP / domain name to refer to services in .env file.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot refer to keycloak with localhost:8080 from another container as it looks up within forms-flow-bpm container for 8080 port. So i recommend you to use the system IP / domain name to refer to services in .env file.
If you are referring to [this](https://github.com/AOT-Technologies/forms-flow-ai/tree/master/deployment/docker) then http://{your-ip-address}:8080 can be replaced with eg: http://192.168.1.100:8080

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by following https://github.com/AOT-Technologies/forms-flow-ai/tree/master/forms-flow-bpm

1. access Keycloak admin, go to clients / form-flow-bpm, and click Credentials tab. Copy secret key
2. copy sample.env to .env and overwrite secret key
3. rebuild docker image
   docker-compose -f docker-compose-windows.yml up --build -d

It should work.